# Restoring Fragment view when pressing back

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments on the screen and one button.
When I press the button, one of the fragments hides and the other fragment changes a little bit its UI (a textview is hidden).

I store this transaction in the backstack so when the user presses back, the hidden fragment shows again. However I don't know how to tell the other fragment (the one that's always been visible) to show again the textview because this change is not part of the transaction.

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite `onBackPressed()` of your `FragmentActivity` in a similar way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (mTextView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        mTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Or use some flag which you can set when you press your button.